# How can I correlate rows in two sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, countif, google-query-language

In a Google Sheet there are two pages with correlated data. On a third page, how can I get a list of all user *name*s that are associated with an *account* that has a *subscription_type*=1?

- Page1 (users) has columns A (name) and B (account_id).
- Page2 (accounts) has columns A (account_id) and B (subscription_type)

Unfortunately, the [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) can only work on one sheet at a time.

Comment: Can you swap name and ID columns in S1 around, so that ID is before name? If you can, you can use `=FILTER( 'S2'!A2:B6 , 'S2'!B2:B6=1)` in S3 , and then do a VLOOKUP() to get the name from S1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, IFNA(VLOOKUP(B:B, Page2!A:B, 2, 0))=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FILTER function to extract from Page 1 the account-id of anybody who  has a subscription_type=1

[image]

After that, you can get the name with a simple INDEX-MATCH

[image]

[You can find an example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJteZAJmcNgZ8WQ7PdNwAQyFSgIag9OE7L-78N7-PdI/edit?usp=sharing).